# Sensor simulator on 2.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a specific problem. I need to make openintents sensor simulator work
on 2.1 emulator. Does anyone has an advice on how to pass around deprecated code and make it work on emulator 2.1. Ty in advance for any help or advice you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sensors are not implemented in the emulator. You need a real device to test code that access sensors within Android.

See the following site about the limitations of the emulator:
http://technotak.blogspot.com/2011/02/what-are-limitations-of-android.html