# Temperature Sensor detection on Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, sensors

I'm trying to check for presence of a temperature sensor on an emulated Android 2.2 device.

Trouble is the emul seems to have only one device built-in, namely: Goldfish 3-axis Accelerometer.

So I installed the openintents sensor sim: http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

At this point I was able to send temperature values of choice from the host computer to Sensor Settings app. In the host app, I could move the temperature slider and see the changes reflecting perfectly in the Sensor Simulator Settings app.

When I tried to do a sensor listing in my app with this simulator running on the emulator (wow!), I did not get to see a temperature sensor, just the goldfish thing mentioned earlier.

My question would be: Is it possible for my app to do a sensor listing and see the simulated temperature sensor?

Code for obtaining sensor list:

```
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    Log.w(LOG, "sl size = " + sensorList.size());
    for(int i=0;i<sensorList.size();i++) {
        Log.w(LOG, "sn = " + sensorList.get(i).getName());
    }
```

I looked up SO and found Peerke saying ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185318/sensor-simulator-on-2-1)) that only real devices can be used for sensor detection. Also he quotes another link ([here](http://technotak.blogspot.in/2011/02/what-are-limitations-of-android.html)) which says Sensor data can be simulated from computer.

Having to test stuff on a real device would be such as big pain as compared to the emul. Welcome your suggestions/thoughts/work-arounds. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh! I should not have been coding well past midnight. Good sleep gave the answer. The openintents program has a "SensorSimulatorSettings" project which is the Android side program. Now taking this as base, I'm writing my app around it to work in sim mode. Later on I will reconfigure to work with real device.